# PyTorch Albert TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Goal: Amend this [Notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/quantization/notebooks/bert/Bert-GLUE_OnnxRuntime_quantization.ipynb) to work with **albert-base-v2** model

Error occurs in **Section 1.3**.

Kernel: `conda_pytorch_p36`. I did Restart & Run All, and refreshed file view in working directory.

---

Section 1.3:

```py
# define the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')

# Evaluate
print('Evaluating PyTorch full precision accuracy and performance:')
time_model_evaluation(model, configs, tokenizer)
```

Output & Traceback:

```
Evaluating PyTorch full precision accuracy and performance:
Evaluating:   0%|          | 0/408 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-6a5db55dd52e> in <module>
    150 # Evaluate the original FP32 BERT model
    151 print('Evaluating PyTorch full precision accuracy and performance:')
--> 152 time_model_evaluation(model, configs, tokenizer)
    153 
    154 # Evaluate the INT8 BERT model after the dynamic quantization

<ipython-input-27-6a5db55dd52e> in time_model_evaluation(model, configs, tokenizer)
    132 def time_model_evaluation(model, configs, tokenizer):
    133     eval_start_time = time.time()
--> 134     result = evaluate(configs, model, tokenizer, prefix="")
    135     eval_end_time = time.time()
    136     eval_duration_time = eval_end_time - eval_start_time

<ipython-input-27-6a5db55dd52e> in evaluate(args, model, tokenizer, prefix)
     53                 if args.model_type != 'distilbert':
     54                     inputs['token_type_ids'] = batch[2] if args.model_type in ['bert', 'xlnet'] else None  # XLM, DistilBERT and RoBERTa don't use segment_ids
---> 55                 outputs = model(**inputs)
     56                 tmp_eval_loss, logits = outputs[:2]
     57 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to post.